# Hibernate has troubles accessing value of annotated property

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate throws exception:

```
    org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
could not get a field value by reflection getter of test.model.Part.part
```

Part entity class:

```
@Table(name = "part")
@Entity
public class Part implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "part")
    private int part;

    public int getPart() {
        return part;
    }

    public void setPart(int part) {
        this.part = part;
        }
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "part")
        private Collection<ProductPart> productPartsByPart;
        public Collection<ProductPart> getProductPartsByPart() {
            return productPartsByPart;
        }
    .....
  }
```

It seems like entity class has correct annotations but Hibernate cannot access property which is `id` and *primary key* in `Part` table. How to solve it?

It gets called:

```
ProductPart productPart  = (ProductPart) sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(ProductPart.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("part", cPartId))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("product", productId)).uniqueResult();
```

**Update:**

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not set int field Part.part   to java.lang.Integer
```

**Update 2:**
I have `product_part` table which has *fk* and references `part` in `part` table. Do I have to use `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "part")` ?

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "part")
public class Part implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "part")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "part")
    private int  part;
```

**UPDATE3**

I don't understand why Hibernate **tries to access** `Part` table when I state that I need to perform search only on `product_part` table. It's also not necessary to access other table since I need only field from product_part which has given values for *part* and *product* (which is both foreign keys)....

**UPDATE4:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_part")
public class ProductPart implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "product", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }


    @JoinColumn(name = "part", referencedColumnName = "part", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Part part;

    public Part getPart() {
        return part;
    }

    public void setPart(Part partByPart) {
        this.part = partByPart;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try invert Entity annotation with the Table annotation?

Comment: Using only the informations you provided, looks like Hibernate is able to access a `getPart()` method, but the int value of field is not set.

If you are trying to access some persistent object, please verify that `part` field on database is correctly set.

Comment: Change your 'part' field type into Integer

Comment: @Snorky35, still having error `Can not set java.lang.Integer field ....  to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: you should refer to part.part, right?

Comment: no, I have to access `product_part` which holds `id` and 2 foreign keys: `part` and `product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your Part referenced in your ProductPart?

should be Something like

```
ProductPart{

@ManyToOne
private Part part;
}
```

guess so

change `.add(Restrictions.eq("part", cPartId))` to `.add(Restrictions.eq("part.part", cPartId))`

**Edit:**

```
ProductPart productPart  = (ProductPart) sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(ProductPart.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("part.part", cPartId))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("product", productId)).uniqueResult();//here similarly access your Product's @Id
                                                                           //something like product.productId
```

Comment: When changed to `.add(Restrictions.eq("product_part.part", cPartId))
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("product_part.product", productId)).uniqueResult();` it gives `QueryException: could not resolve property: product_part of: test.model.ProductPart` where `product_part` is the table where we search

Comment: @RCola, can you post your productpart class?

Comment: @RCola,your productpart does not have product_part property. so what you are doing is wrong. try my edit , if it works then I'll explain the things.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it fixed the problem when I also changed this `.add(Restrictions.eq("product.product", productId))`. To me this doesn't make sense because hibernate have to deal only with `product_part` table but this `product.product` states  it's accessing `product` table as well. WHY?

Comment: as part and product are foreignkeys it should go to the original tables to get the entire object or row. You only have productid and partid in your product_part table, right?Keeping that aside, Also, you are passing partId and productId as argumetnts which are integers,if I'm correct. how can you check equals on type Part to type Int? so that's why you have to access part.part which is an int for partId to match.Hope you got it.

Comment: `how can you check equals on type Part to type Int?` - why would I need that if I am only performing search on product_part table?

Comment: because when you say .add(Restrictions.eq("part", cPartId)), what is part type in your productpart entity, it is of type Part, right? and what is cPartId, it is int , right? so even though you search on product_part table, product_part.part is of type Part which cannot be compared to an integer, but part.part is an integer on which you need to perform your equals with cPartId, sorry for a lengthy message

Comment: I think I got confused because `part` and `product` from `product_part` tale are both defined in MySQL schema as of type `int`. Now I see that Hibernate consider it as objects and have to link it properly by accessing each of these objects...if I understand correctly....